# Linq Union of two queries throws null exception on string assignment

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two queries where the first one returns organization with departments and the second one returns organizations without departments and after that I use `Union()` for my final query since I want to display in table both results.

`Union()` requires to have fulfilled exactly the same properties in both queries so I had to assign "Empty" `Department` object in second query, but I need to have my `Department Name` empty and it throws me `null exception` and I have no idea why it should even throw it, it doesnt make sense to me.

When I tried to assign for example `organization.Name` into `Department.Name` suddently it didnt throw me `null exception` at all.

Is there any possibility to assign empty string into `Department name`?

```
var query1 = UserAccountOwnSuppliers
                .Where(organization => organization.IsBuyer)
                    .SelectMany(organization => organization.Departments
                        .Select(department =>
                            new UserAccountMarketsForSupplierDTO
                            {
                                Organization = new OrganizationBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = organization.Id,
                                    Name = organization.Name,
                                    RegionId = organization.RegionId,
                                    CreatorDepartmentId = organization.CreatorDepartmentId,
                                    CreatorOrganizationId = organization.CreatorOrganizationId,
                                    CreatorId = organization.CreatorId,
                                },
                                Department = new DepartmentBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = department.Id,
                                    Name = department.Name
                                }
                            })).OrderBy(dto => dto.Organization.Name);

        var query2 = UserAccountOwnSuppliers
            .Where(organization => organization.IsBuyer)
            .Select(organization => new UserAccountMarketsForSupplierDTO
            {
                Organization = new OrganizationBaseDTO
                {
                    Id = organization.Id,
                    Name = organization.Name,
                    RegionId = organization.RegionId,
                    CreatorDepartmentId = organization.CreatorDepartmentId,
                    CreatorOrganizationId = organization.CreatorOrganizationId,
                    CreatorId = organization.CreatorId,
                },
                Department = new DepartmentBaseDTO
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    //here it throws null exception when I try to assign some value
                    Name = "---"
                }
            }).OrderBy(dto => dto.Organization.Name); ;

        var query = query2.Union(query1);

        return query.OrderBy(dto => dto.Organization.Name);
```

DTOs

```
public class DepartmentBaseDTO : IEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationBaseDTO : IEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int? RegionId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccountMarketsForSupplierDTO : IEntity<int>
{
    public OrganizationBaseDTO Organization { get; set; } = new OrganizationBaseDTO();
    public DepartmentBaseDTO Department { get; set; } = new DepartmentBaseDTO();     
}
```

StackTrace
https://pastebin.com/j81yBYYU

Comment: Can you please show class DepartmentBaseDTO ?

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I edited my question and updated with all Dtos which take parts in this query

Comment: Are your sure exception comes from                   //here it throws null exception when I try to assign some value    . At which point does your debugger stop?

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I get it when `Execute` is performed on my query in my facade method. I edited question and added stacktrace

Comment: try to put UserAccountOwnSuppliers.ToArray().Where(... instead of UserAccountOwnSuppliers.Where(...   So it will execute query in memory. What will be the result?

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy now it throws me: source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<UserAccountMarketsForSupplierDTO>. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: Sounds strange, I think you should try to simplify what are you doing until you have a few basic instructions that reproduce the issue

Comment: I hope I will figure it out, anyway thanks for your time.